# best way to use jquery or javascript as its disturbing other elements on page when using from admin side

Tags: magento2

I made a page using admin panel

```
content->pages
```

And after pasting all html I added javascript at the end of this page like this. After adding working fine but some navbar dropdown is not working after using JavaScript through this way.Any other way to do this ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" xml="space">// <![CDATA[
    window.onload = function() {
        beforeAfter.init();
    };
    ]]></script>
```

Comment: Do you have errors in javascript console?

Comment: @EvgenyLevinsky  yes as I am using mega menu  so error is    Uncaught TypeError: topMenuContainer.ultramegamenu is not a function